# How to preserve results from Maximize in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maximize

I aim to calculate and preserve the results from the maximization of a function with two arguments and one exogenous parameter, when the maximum can not be derived (in closed form) by maximize. For instance, let

```
f[x_,y_,a_]=Max[0,Min[a-y,1-x-y]
```

be the objective function where `a` is positive. The maximization shall take place over `[0,1]^2`, therefore I set

```
m[a_]=Maximize[{f[x, y, a], 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= a}, {x,y}]
```

Obviously `m` can be evaluated at any point `a` and it is therefore possible to plot the maximizing `x` by employing

```
Plot[x /. m[a][[2]], {a, 0.01, 1}]
```

As I need to do several plots and further derivations containing the optimal solutions `x` and `y` (which of course are functions of `a`), i would like to preserve/save the results from the optimization for further use. Is there an elegant way to do this, or do I have to write some kind of loop to extract the values myself?

Comment: Is your use of `=` in your function definitions deliberate ?  Or have you perhaps mis-written `:=` in your haste to post your question ?  Or, perhaps you are such a new user of Mathematica that you have not yet understood the difference between `=` and `:=`.  If this is the case haste ye to the documentation.

Comment: @High Performace Mark If I am not mistaken, using `:=` instead of `=` would delay the calculation in the sence that (from the documentation)

_lhs:=rhs
assigns rhs to be the delayed value of lhs. rhs is maintained in an 
unevaluated form. When lhs appears, it is replaced by rhs, evaluated afresh each time._

I aim for the exact opposite, that is, I want the maximization to be executed once and store its result as a function of the parameter a.
As I am a fairly new user of Mathematica, please correct me if I did misunderstand your comment.

Comment: Your comment on my comment does not suggest to me that you have properly understood the difference in semantics between `Set` (usually written `=`) and `SetDelayed` (usually written `:=`).  But this may be only my misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, I will read the documentation again and (just to be sure) try the different possibilities. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I've seen the full text of your comment on my original comment, I suspect that you do understand the differences between `Set` and `SetDelayed` well enough.  I think what you may be looking for is memoisation, sometimes implemented a bit like this;

```
f[x_,y_] := f[x,y] = Max[0,Min[a-y,1-x-y]]
```

When you evaluate, for example `f[3,4]` for the first time it will evaluate to the entire expression to the right of the `:=`.  The rhs is the assignment `f[3,4] = Max[0,Min[a-y,1-x-y]]`.  Next time you evaluate `f[3,4]` Mathematica already has a value for it so doesn't need to recompute it, it just recalls it. In this example the stored value would be `Max[0,Min[a-4,-6]]` of course.

I remain a little uncertain of what you are trying to do so this answer may not be any use to you at all.

Comment: Thank you, High Performance Mark this was exactly the thing I was looking for!

Comment: I would like to add another question (if I should rather submit this as a new question, please let me know):

As the evaluation of the function mentioned above takes some time, getting a plot from it takes (in my specific case) hours. Is there a way to save/export the results accomplished by plotting the function, such that I dont have to run the evaluation of the function again when I reopen the document?

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach

```
results = Table[{x, y, a} /. m[a][[2]], {a, 0.01, 1, .01}]
ListPlot[{#[[3]], #[[1]]} & /@ results, Joined -> True]
```

(The Set = is ok here so long as 'a' is not previosly defined )

If you want to utilise Plot[]s automatic evaluation take a look at Reap[]/Sow[]

```
{p, data} = Reap[Plot[x /. Sow[m[a]][[2]], {a, 0.01, 1}]];
Show[p]
```

(this takes a few minutes as the function output is  a mess..).

hmm try this again: assuming you want x,y,a and the minimum value:

```
{p, data} = Reap[Plot[x /. Sow[{a, m[a]}][[2, 2]], {a, 0.01, .1}]];
Show[p]
results = {#[[1]], x /. #[[2, 2]], y /. #[[2, 2]], #[[2, 1]]} & /@  data[[1]]
```

BTW Your function appears to be independent of x over some ranges which is why the plot is a mess..